# Python: compare many columns to one column and replace values greater than that column with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My overall goal is to remove outliers in a row that are higher than the 1.5xIQR of the that row. I have a large dataframe with thousands of features which mainly consists of numeric data. I have calculated the 1.5xIQR in a row-wise fashion and set it as a new column. I would like to replace any data within each row that is greater than its respective 1.5xIQR with either NaN (preferred) or 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4),), columns=list('ABCD'))
df

    A   B   C   D
0   46  99  38  11
1   43  49  3   95
2   64  39  33  49
3   41  60  49  7
4   38  95  70  13
5   11  45  57  73
6   8   62  57  22
7   9   83  89  91
8   47  82  61  40
9   34  21  21  41
```

I have tried numerous variations of this and beyond with no success.

`df1 = df.iloc[:,:] > df.loc['D'] = 'NaN'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4),), columns=list('ABCD'))

s = df.apply(lambda x: (x.quantile(.75)-x.quantile(.25))*1.5, axis=1)
df=df.where(df.lt(s, axis=0),np.nan)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
def f(row):
    Q1 = row.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = row.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    row[row > 1.5*IQR] = np.nan
    return row

df1 = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from the wording of question and your tried code is that you have already calculated the 1.5xIQR in column D.  As such, you can use [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) as follows:

```
df1 = df.mask(df.gt(df['D'], axis=0), np.nan)
```

Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4),), columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df)

     A   B   C   D
0   45  71  15  22
1   56  68  62  91
2   21  90  44  15
3   60  87  2   68
4   48  21  22  25
5   60  68  67  60
6   74  97  94  27
7   69  26  56  85
8   39  42  74  73
9   23  99  91  72
 
df1 = df.mask(df.gt(df['D'], axis=0), np.nan)

print(df1)
       A       B       C     D
0    NaN     NaN    15.0    22
1   56.0    68.0    62.0    91
2    NaN     NaN     NaN    15
3   60.0     NaN     2.0    68
4    NaN    21.0    22.0    25
5   60.0     NaN     NaN    60
6    NaN     NaN     NaN    27
7   69.0    26.0    56.0    85
8   39.0    42.0     NaN    73
9   23.0     NaN     NaN    72
```

Alternatively, you can also use the simplified code below to update df elements meeting the criteria in place:

```
df[df.gt(df['D'], axis=0)] = np.nan
```

Printing df after the code will give the same result.